# Jenkins pipeline to prompt whether to Proceed or Abort the build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am building a jenkins pipeline for a product and have accidentally clicked on build now a few times which unwantedly deployed it to production.
I added a feature to my pipeline so that every time the pipeline is built, it asks for an input whether to Proceed or Abort the build but I also want the default value of the build to be Proceed if no prompt is entered. I need the default timeout to be 1 minute. I have updated the pipeline code below but the build does not default to proceed

The pipeline code

pipeline {
agent any

```
stages {
    stage('Checkout') {
        steps {
            cleanWs()
            checkout scm
        }
    }

    stage('User Confirmation') {
        steps {
            script {
                def proceedWithBuild = true // Default to true
                try {
                    timeout(time: 1, unit: 'MINUTES') {
                        def userInput = input(
                            id: 'userInput',
                            message: 'Do you want to proceed with the build?',
                            parameters: [
                                choice(
                                    choices: ['Yes', 'Abort'],
                                    description: 'Click "Yes" to proceed or "Abort" to cancel.',
                                    name: 'PROCEED'
                                )
                            ]
                        )
                        if (userInput == 'Abort') {
                            proceedWithBuild = false
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // Timeout occurred - proceedWithBuild remains true
                    echo "Timeout occurred - proceeding with the build by default."
                }

                if (!proceedWithBuild) {
                    currentBuild.result = 'ABORTED'
                    return
                }
            }
        }
    }

    stage('Build Product') {
        steps {
            sh 'chmod a+rx deployment.sh'
            sh './deployment.sh'
        }
    }
}

post {
    always {
        cleanWs()
        echo 'Jenkins pipeline finished!'
    }
    success {
        echo 'Deployment was successful'
    }
    failure {
        emailext(
            subject: "Pipeline Failed: ${env.JOB_NAME}",
            body: "The pipeline ${env.BUILD_NUMBER} has failed. Please investigate.",
            to: "abc@xyz.com"
        )
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Was able to fix the code so that the build prompts to either Proceed or Abort the build and the build works fine. I added default timeout of 1 minute and want the build to proceed if no option is selected. But that logic does not work.

Comment: Could you modify your question accordingly?

Comment: Updated the question and the pipeline code accordingly